# I cant customize my GridPane pragmatically in JavaFx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, gridpane

I am doing a JavaFx project connected to documentum data storage . I need to retrieve some data from the data storage , insert and organize them in the tabular shape in which I'm using GridPanes . Since the data varies from one object to another I had to make my code dynamic and used programmatic GUI design . Well , there is no problem in data fetching and uploading them into the GridPane . However , I am facing some problems in designing the interface of that GridPan . I have created a GridPane called "aclInfo" in my FXML file and I am trying to create my new GridPane inside of it . The following the code I've written :

```
public void test ( ){
    aclInfo.getChildren().clear();

try{


    for (int i = 0 ; i <= listOfAcls.size() - 1 ; i ++ ){

        GridPane mainGridPane = new GridPane();

        mainGridPane.setStyle("-fx-grid-lines-visible: true");
        //mainGridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color :red");


        RowConstraints row0 = new RowConstraints();
        RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
        row0.setMinHeight(20);
        row1.setMinHeight(32);

        mainGridPane.getRowConstraints().addAll(row0 , row1);


        ColumnConstraints mianCol0 = new ColumnConstraints();



        mianCol0.setMinWidth(911);


        mainGridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(mianCol0 );


        GridPane title = new GridPane ();
        ColumnConstraints col0 = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col0.setMinWidth(303.66);
        col1.setMinWidth(303.66);
        col2.setMinWidth(303.66);
        title.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col0 , col1 , col2);


        //title.setStyle("-fx-grid-lines-visible: true");

        GridPane desc = new GridPane();
        RowConstraints descrow0 = new RowConstraints();
        RowConstraints descrow1 = new RowConstraints();
        descrow0.setMinHeight(20);
        descrow0.setMinHeight(22);

        desc.getRowConstraints().addAll(descrow0 , descrow1);


        ColumnConstraints desccol0 = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints desccol1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints desccol2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        desccol0.setMinWidth(303.66);
        desccol1.setMinWidth(303.66);
        desccol2.setMinWidth(303.66);

        desc.getColumnConstraints().addAll( desccol0, desccol1,desccol2);
        //desc.setStyle("-fx-background-color :red");
        desc.setStyle("-fx-grid-lines-visible: true");


        Text aclName = new Text(listOfAcls.get(0));
        Text roid = new Text ("r_object_id");
        Text rap = new Text ("r_accessor_permit");
        Text ran = new Text ("r_accessor_name");
        Text roidValue = new Text (holding.get(i).r_object_id);
        Text rapValue = new Text (holding.get(i).r_accessor_permit);
        Text ranValue = new Text (holding.get(i).r_accessor_name);





        title.add(aclName, 1, 0);
        title.setHalignment(aclName, HPos.CENTER);
        desc.add(roid , 0 , 0 );
        desc.setHalignment(roid, HPos.CENTER);
        desc.add(ran , 1 , 0 );
        desc.add(rap , 2 , 0 );
        desc.add(roidValue, 0 , 1);
        desc.add(rapValue, 1 , 1);
        desc.add(ranValue, 2 , 1);

        mainGridPane.add(title, 0, 0);
        mainGridPane.add(desc, 0, 1);
        aclInfo.add(mainGridPane, 0 , i);


    }




}catch(Exception e){
    Alert alert = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.ERROR , e.getLocalizedMessage());
    alert.showAndWait();
}

}
}
```

I can not manage to centerize my text inside the GridPane .

Any idea where am I making mistake :)

Comment: It will be good if you can put all code, because it is difficult to reconstruct everything. For 2  you get property but you have to set property: aclInfo.setGridLinesVisible(true); and for 3 use also: aclName.setWrappingWidth(double value) you have to set width for wrapping

Comment: @BadVegan Thanks for your comment . It was helpful . But I have faced another question . When I set true as the argument of  " setGridLinesVisible() " I get asked to remove that argument . However, when I use css it works fine . Any idea why ? ;)

Comment: hmm i don't know how it is possible,     GridPane gridpane = new GridPane(); gridpane.setGridLinesVisible(true); if i declare something like this it works and i see the lines

Comment: @BadVegan True. I was mistakenly using another similar function which is " gridLinesVisible()" instead of " setGridLinesVisible()" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also put alignment for all column:

```
ColumnConstraints desccol0 = new ColumnConstraints();
desccol0.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
ColumnConstraints desccol1 = new ColumnConstraints();
desccol0.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
ColumnConstraints desccol2 = new ColumnConstraints();
desccol0.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
```

or row

```
 RowConstraints descrow1 = new RowConstraints();
 descrow1.setValignment(VPos.CENTER);
```

and you have less code

Answer (score 0):

Well , Here id how the final working code look like :

```
   public void test ( ){
    aclInfo.getChildren().clear();

try{


    for (int i = 0 ; i <= listOfAcls.size() - 1 ; i ++ ){

        GridPane mainGridPane = new GridPane();

        mainGridPane.setStyle("-fx-grid-lines-visible: true");
        //mainGridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color :red");


        RowConstraints row0 = new RowConstraints();
        RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
        row0.setMinHeight(20);
        row1.setMinHeight(32);

        mainGridPane.getRowConstraints().addAll(row0 , row1);


        ColumnConstraints mianCol0 = new ColumnConstraints();



        mianCol0.setMinWidth(911);


        mainGridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(mianCol0 );


        GridPane title = new GridPane ();
        ColumnConstraints col0 = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        col0.setMinWidth(303.66);
        col1.setMinWidth(303.66);
        col2.setMinWidth(303.66);
        title.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col0 , col1 , col2);



        GridPane desc = new GridPane();
        RowConstraints descrow0 = new RowConstraints();
        RowConstraints descrow1 = new RowConstraints();
        descrow0.setMinHeight(20);
        descrow0.setMinHeight(22);

        desc.getRowConstraints().addAll(descrow0 , descrow1);


        ColumnConstraints desccol0 = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints desccol1 = new ColumnConstraints();
        ColumnConstraints desccol2 = new ColumnConstraints();
        desccol0.setMinWidth(303.66);
        desccol1.setMinWidth(303.66);
        desccol2.setMinWidth(303.66);

        desc.getColumnConstraints().addAll( desccol0, desccol1,desccol2);

        desc.setStyle("-fx-grid-lines-visible: true");


        Text aclName = new Text(listOfAcls.get(0));
        Text roid = new Text ("r_object_id");
        Text rap = new Text ("r_accessor_permit");
        Text ran = new Text ("r_accessor_name");
        Text roidValue = new Text (holding.get(i).r_object_id);
        Text rapValue = new Text (holding.get(i).r_accessor_permit);
        Text ranValue = new Text (holding.get(i).r_accessor_name);





        title.add(aclName, 1, 0);

        desc.add(roid , 0 , 0 );
        title.setHalignment(aclName, HPos.CENTER);
        desc.setHalignment(roid, HPos.CENTER);
        desc.setHalignment(ran, HPos.CENTER );
        desc.setHalignment(rap, HPos.CENTER );

        desc.setHalignment(roidValue, HPos.CENTER);
        desc.setHalignment(ranValue, HPos.CENTER );
        desc.setHalignment(rapValue, HPos.CENTER );


        desc.add(ran , 1 , 0 );
        desc.add(rap , 2 , 0 );
        desc.add(roidValue, 0 , 1);
        desc.add(rapValue, 1 , 1);
        desc.add(ranValue, 2 , 1);

        mainGridPane.add(title, 0, 0);
        mainGridPane.add(desc, 0, 1);
        aclInfo.add(mainGridPane, 0 , i);


    }




}catch(Exception e){
    Alert alert = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.ERROR , e.getLocalizedMessage());
    alert.showAndWait();
}

}
}
```